# Java - remove items in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList `tmpOnBoard` with `MoveTo` objects. A `MoveTo` object is made from two other objects a `Position` and a `Piece`.

```
MoveTo.toString;
```

out:

```
MoveTo: wG1 (0,0)
```

wG1 is the notation of a piece and
(0,0) is the x/y coordinate of the piece.

`tmpOnBoard` is made in a method that is triggered by a listener so it changes all the time.

What has to happen is, if there is two or more `MoveTo` objects in `tmpOnBoard` with the same `Piece` but an other `Position`.

```
 [MoveTo: bS1 (-1,2), MoveTo: bS1 (2,-2)]
```

All the `MoveTo` objects with the same `Piece` should be removed except the last one so the list is

```
[MoveTo: bS1 (2,-2)]
```

Another example:

```
 [MoveTo: wB1 (-1,2), MoveTo: bG2 (0,0), ... MoveTo: wB1 (2,-2), MoveTo: wB1 (-7,4)]
```

Should go to

```
 [MoveTo: bG2 (0,0), ... MoveTo: wB1 (-7,4)]
```

A `MoveTo` object has a getter for a `Piece` and a `Position`

Things I tried:

```
List<Piece> ref = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MoveTo moveTo : tmpOnBoard) {
            ref.add(moveTo.getPiece());
            if (ref.contains(moveTo.getPiece())) {
                tmpOnBoard.remove(moveTo);
            }
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I tried several things but none of them worked. So my question is basically how do you do that.

Comment: Please clarify - what part of this are you having trouble with? What code have you written so far to begin to solve this? "Several things" and "none of them worked" doesn't give us much to go on. Please don't expect people here to solve entire problems for you from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps use of a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is what you're after, adding in Piece and MoveTo objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: don't use an ArrayList to hold your MoveTo objects but rather use a `LinkedHashMap<Piece, MoveTo>`. When you add a new MoveTo object to this Map, use the same Key that is in the MoveTo object. This will give you a list-like structure that maintains order of insertion, and also does not allow duplicate key entry. So if your Map contains an entry for a certain Piece, and you add a new entry for the same Piece, the old entry will be discarded.

Caveat: Be sure that your Piece class has decent `public boolean equals(Object o)` and `public int hashCode()` method, ones that behaves as expected.

Comment: the LinkedHashmap worked!

Comment: @user138770: I'm glad it did, but again, please look at my warning above. Your Piece class absolutely has to have a decent equals and hashCode method. If you're unclear of this, you'd better study this subject since it is of key importance.